# Why not crack a password a character at a time?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking

Brute force can be used to crack passwords by trying a large number of passwords.
Why does no one try the brute force approach on every single character of the password instead?

Comment: You need to look at how password hashing works - for most modern storage methods, you can't check a part of the password as a separate step. It's either the whole password correct, or you don't know how wrong you are.

Comment: You can't brute force parts of a password because you only get a confirmation whether the *entire* password is correct -- not for a selected part or a single character.

Comment: I edited the title to make it clearer. I hope my edits were in line with what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @utkarshdev, Are you speaking of offline brute force?

Comment: Depends on the type of thing you're bruteforcing. For example in a blind SQL injection attack, bruteforcing a character at a time is perfectly possible (although there are better ways), but for a hashed password, no you can't.

Comment: @Eclipse Well, you can get the characters in the hash, one at a time... Done that before!

Comment: You can only crack passwords a character at a time in movies or tv shows.

Comment: @matthew could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Because most operating systems *[hash](https://www.wired.com/2016/06/hacker-lexicon-password-hashing/)* passwords once entered (and store them in a database).  This means that the entire password is converted into a collection of cryptographic hashes, random-looking strings of characters into which the passwords have been mathematically transformed to prevent them from being misused.

So, once a password is hashed for a well defined hash, there is no way to attack each character.  That is circular logic. *To attack each character you must know each character.  To know each character you must attack each character*.

Comment: And one of the attributes of a good cryptographic hash function is that a small change results in a very different hash, so you can't tell if you're close.

Comment: I think you should add "for a well designed hash" to the last statement.  The Lanman hash, for instance could attack sub-sections of the password at one time, which significantly weakened the hash.  Not character by character, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Your point is noted, and I agree.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If by *cracking* you mean breaking a given hash of password(s) then it isn't possible since hash functions are built to have seemingly random outputs, so for example:
The [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash of 'Password' is:

```
SHA-1(Password) = 8be3c943b1609fffbfc51aad666d0a04adf83c9d
```

but change *only* the first character ('Sassword') and you get:

```
SHA-1(Sassword) = 1243263916a8d81369235831d5a224bbae87a86a
```

As others have mentioned, hash functions are made to appear this way just for this purpose; to thwart attempts to 'crack' them.

If by *cracking* you mean brute forcing a user's login credientials to a site, then it is even more clear why it wouldn't work - you won't get feedback from the site saying "The first letter was correct, but the rest wasn't", etc.